# Custom PyTorch Dataloader that provides batches of a subset of the full data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, dataloader

I would like a PyTorch `DataLoader` that can be iterated over to provide a batch of data that is from subsample of the full data set.

Example: I have a data set with `N` data points. I subsample this `S` times at a rate of `r` by randomly generating (without repetition) `r x N` indicies `S` times. I would then like a dataloader that does something along the lines of:

```py
for i in range(S):
    for batch_idx, (X, y) in DataLoader(S):
        # X, y from subsample S only
        pred = model(X)
```

The data should then be shuffled after each epoch but such that the indicies of the subsample respect the shuffling i.e. they are equivalently changed.

I think I want something similar [`torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler) but this is mutually exclusive with shuffling.